# Comparing UTF-8 string from databese with input strings (PHP/SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, compare

I am trying to compare two stirngs, one is from input, and other is in datebase.
I have this list of names in databases and I want to check if the name already exist in database, but problem is special characters from serbian latin (Č,Ć,Đ,Ž,Š). Connection has UTF-8 charset mysqli_set_charset($this->con, 'utf8'), and DB has utf-8_unicode_ci collation.

```
   $names = Teachers::returnTeachers();
  if(isset($_GET['idRequest']) && $_GET['idRequest'] == 1)
    {
$firstName = trim($_GET['firstname']);
$status = "";


   foreach($name as $names)
{
    if(strtolower(trim($names['firstname'])) == $firstName)
    {
        echo "This name is already in DB";
        $status = "exist";
    }
       echo "No name";
       $status="not exist";
}
```

If I have name like "Novak Đoković" in DB, and I enter "Novak Đoković" in input it will say that name doesn't exist. I can't use incov() because C, Ć or Č have different meaning. Man with name Colović it's not same as man with name Čolović.

P.S. When I echo names from DB, special characters appear normal, not like question mark symbols.

EDIT : adding some code from comments

```
public static function returnTeachers(){ 
    $all = []; 
    $rs = Conection::query("SELECT firstname FROM teachers");
    while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) { 
        array_push($all,$row); 
    } 
    return $all; 
 }
```

Comment: classic XY ? Please post what your `$names` looks like when returned from `returnTeachers()` ? is it an array, an array of what, associative ? ... you probably have a simple logic error in the formulation of your foreach (ie not an UTF8 issue at all)

Comment: public static function returnTeachers(){

$all = [];

        $rs = Conection::query("SELECT firstname FROM teachers");

        while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
        {
            array_push($all,$row);
        }

        return $nizSvih;

}


I'm sure return is not a problem, because when I enter name without special characters it works just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally  pressed enter(look again)

Comment: just a guess then, try ; `foreach($names as $name)`  and `trim($name['firstName']`

Comment: Both values are trimmed, one form DB and one from input.
$firstName = trim($_GET['firstname']); (input)
strtolower(trim($names['firstname'])) - (if statment, name from DB)

Comment: My mistake, again. I'm translating my code  here, and i forgot to translate it. It returns $all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`utf8_unicode_ci` is somewhat "generic", and fails to follow the specific requirements, such as what you have for Serbian.

I do not see a 'serbian' collation, but there are several that might come close enough.  Look at http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html

Note that utf8_croatian_ci treats `C` and `Č` and `Ć` as separate "letters".  Czech, Slovak, and Polish (and others) do some of that.  Ditto for `Ž` and `Š`.

`Ð` is treated as a separate letter by every collation *except* utf8_unicode_520_ci.

So, pick one of the other collations.  `utf8_croatian_ci` seems closest to what you need since it is the only one that treats `C` and `Č` and `Ć` as distinct.

Comment: Still have a problem, but thank you anyway. I will fix my ajax and jQuery code, and then try again. I think it will work.